# Analyzing time complexity of this not so simple recursion

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I gave the following solution (I think the solution is ok, not sure), but couldn't analyze it's time complexity.

If anyone's interested, this is the question: (if not, skip to the code):

Your input is `D` - a set of words, and `s` -  a string without spaces. Write a method to count the number of legal division of `s`, such that a legal division is defined as such that all the words that were partitioned from `s` are in `D`. For example, if `D` contains `{run,time,runtime}` then for `s="runtime"` the answer should be 2: the first one is the empty partition (meaning, just the word `runtime`) and the second one is partitioning `s` to `"run"` and `"time"`

This is my solution (pseudo):

```
int CountPartitions(string s)
{
    if (s.Length == 0)
        return 1;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length ; ++i)
    {
        string prefix = s.substring(0,i);
        if (D.cotains(prefix))
        {
            result += CountPartitions(s.substring(i+1,s.Length));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The way I see it, the time complexity of the function is given by:

`T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)+...+T(1)`
Where `T(1)` is constant assuming that querying the dictionary can be done in constant time, however, I don't know how to solve this equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm and the recurrence equation seems to be correct.

To compute the time-complexity you count the number of `T(1)` showing up in the expanded expression of `T(n)`.

Let `N(n)` be the number of `T(1)`'s showing up in `T(n)` after expanding it.
e.g. `T(3) = T(2) + T(1) = T(1) + T(1)` so `N(3) = 2`.
I will use [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to prove `N(n) = 2^(n-2)` for all `n >= 2`

```
n = 1: T(1) = T(1) => N(1) = 1
n = 2: T(2) = T(1) => N(2) = 1 = 2^(2-2)
n = 3: T(3) = 2*T(1) => N(3) = 2 = 2^(3-2)
```

so let `N(k) = 2^(k-2)` be correct for all `2 < k <= n`:

```
T(n+1) = T(n) + T(n-1) + ... + T(1) 
=> N(n+1) = N(n) + ... N(1)
          = 2^(n-2) + 2^(n-3) + ... 2^(n-n) + 1
          = ( 2(n-1) - 1 ) + 1
          = 2^(n-1)
```

So, now we know that `N(n) = 2^(n-2)` is correct. So the complexity of your algorithm is Θ(2^n).

If you only want to have upper or lower bounds you can use a trick:

```
n/2 * T(n/2) <= T(n) <= (n-1) * T(n-1)
```

This gives you easily the upper bound O((n-1)!) and the lower bound Ω(n^(log n)).